# JAVA - If-then assistance needed

Tags: java, if-statement, jframe

I want to set up an 'if-then' statement for the entire program. I want:

```
if (health <= 0) {
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You lost");
}
```

I can't get it to work properly. I am trying to make a very basic text-based game and it won't constantly check for health. I don't know how to get it to do that without writing it every time there is damage done.

Comment: Use a while loop and put your code in there. Or check for the health each time an action that changes health is used.

Comment: Look up the game design concept of the "game loop". At one point during each loop, check for the health.

Comment: @Jeroen I didn't want to check the health every time there was damage though.

Comment: You could also update the `health` counter with a setter method. That was you could check whenever the setter was called. It's also good practice to use getters and setters to manage variables like "health".

Comment: Why would you not check health every time there was damage? I would think you'd have to... If you think you're being more efficient by not checking it every time, drop that thought. Integer comparison is very cheap and in a game-like situation where human input takes place, negligible.

Comment: @PaulSasik, there has to be a way to not have to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure how you're implementing taking damage, but if it's in a method, you could do something like this:

```
private void takeDamage(double damage)
{
  // Take the damage here. Then check the health.
  if (health <= 0) 
  {
    // Print the you lost message.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a damage-doing and healing function, such as:

```
public void changeHealth(int amount) {
    health += amount;
    if (health <= 0) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You lost");
    }
}
```

And then, for example, do

```
changeHealth(-10);
```

Instead of

```
health -= 10
```

---

It would be better to have a `Player` class that takes care of the health and weapon and things, but that may be too advanced for you. You could start out like this:

```
public class Player {
    private int health;
    public Player(int startHealth) {
        this.health = startHealth;
    }
    public void changeHealth(int amount) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Save it in a file called `Player.java`, and use it like this:

```
Player p = new Player(100); // create a Player with 100 hp
p.changeHealth(-10); // ouch
```

[Learn more about OOP here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/).

Comment: Thanks. It is quite a bit more advanced than I am but thanks for trying to help =)